# How to (not) tell an potential Employer that I am unreliable?

Tags: interviewing, employment-gaps

I am 24 and normally an University Student. I do not have any Job Experience in my Field. And I am currently looking for an Job. I am already an year over the normal time.

This term I forgot to enroll for the University and thus cannot study util March. Due to the fact that I don´t want to study for four years and then have nothing I will of course begin next term again. So I want to get an Job as a Programmer. - Month´s ago I was already looking half-heartly for an part-time Job, but now I am looking for Full-time "aggressively".
I am planning to have that Job now Full time and later flexi or maybe some hours less for study.

Now I am afraid what I shall tell an Interviewer. **How shall I handle the Situation if someone asks me why I did not enrolled in time?**

My problem is that an Interviewer could think that this is still affecting me and my Workforce.
I even thought about bluntly lie to him and say that I am studying, but I think that this is a terrible idea.

Furthermore **how can I express that I will study again** and will probably need for that time then **less hours**, but still want to stay with them?

For Clarification: I lost two Persons precious to me and I was not... "myself" for some time (what I do NOT want to express at an Interview). Furthermore they changed the enrolling Process, what didn´t helped either.

Excuse my English, I am German.

Comment: If someone ask you, you tell them you were dealing with a family emergency.

Comment: @keshlam so you suggest the author lie?  Better ways to answer other than a lie

Answer (score 18):

Focus on the underlying reason, not that you missed the deadline:  "I was unable to begin the semester due to difficult family circumstances, so I'm taking a semester off and intend to return in (month)."

You want to convey that your family situation *was* a problem but *isn't one now*.  It's important to use the past tense there.  Since, even though it's now resolved, you can't just jump back into your university program mid-semester, employers should understand this.

This is similar to the approach taken by people who've had employment gaps due to family issues, poor health, etc -- you explain that there was an issue (that meant you couldn't work), *it's over now*, and you're ready to get back on track.

I'm in the US, not Germany, and my experience in such matters is on the interviewer side, not the interviewee side.

Comment: Yep, this is a reasonable explanation

Answer (score 2):

**You have taken a gap year.**

*How shall I handle the Situation if someone asks me why I did not enrolled in time?*

Why would they know you have not enrolled in time ? In France, it is not unusual to take a gap year before the last study year, in order to have a better understanding of the professionnal world, and help you choose the most adequate specialty for your last year. It also allows for a better entry in your first *stable* job when you graduate, since you already have a valuable experience.

Once you have built up the arguments for a gap year applicable to your personal situation, you can explain this company why they are the best choice for you and your gap year. Underline for how long you are available, and tell them that you are willing to work for them again once your studies are complete.

On a personal note, I used this gap-year justification for a *failed* year, and no employer ever questioned it.

Comment: +1 I'm from germany and I took a gap year aswell. I agree that it is not uncommon to do this. Nobody questioned my either